# How to use google/gin-config with python?

Tags: python

First, i already followed the instructions on project site, and still have no idea how to use it.
There is structure of my folder:

```
Folder
|________use_gin.py
     |___config.gin
     |___test.py
```

inside `use_gin.py`:

```
import gin   

@gin.configurable
def my_other_func(a, b, c):
  return a, b, c
```

inside `config.gin`:

```
my_other_func.a = -2.9
my_other_func.b = 9.3

# Comments!
my_other_func.c = 'Oh, Dear.'
```

and i use test.py to call the `my_other_func`function, and it gives error:

```
C:/Anaconda3/envs/py3/python.exe d:/Folder/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Folder/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    my_other_func()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\envs\py3tf\lib\site-packages\gin\config.py", line 1032, in wrapper
    utils.augment_exception_message_and_reraise(e, err_str)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\envs\py3tf\lib\site-packages\gin\utils.py", line 48, in augment_exception_message_and_reraise
    six.raise_from(proxy.with_traceback(exception.__traceback__), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\envs\py3tf\lib\site-packages\gin\config.py", line 1009, in wrapper
    return fn(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
TypeError: my_other_func() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', and 'c'
  No values supplied by Gin or caller for arguments: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  Gin had values bound for: []
  Caller supplied values for: []
  In call to configurable 'my_other_func' (<function my_other_func at 0x00000000029C8268>)
```

is there something wrong on my setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only do in your test.py, before using `my_other_func()`,

```
import gin
gin.parse_config_file('config.gin')
```

Read around [here](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/gin-config-0.1.1/autoapi/config/index.html#config.parse_config_file) for more details.

Comment: the link doesn't work anymore. can you elaborate on why this error is happening?

Answer (score 0):

congig.gin

```
import use_gin
my_other_func.a = -2.9
my_other_func.b = 9.3

# Comments!
my_other_func.c = 'Oh, Dear.'
```

test.py

```
import gin
gin.parse_config_file('config.gin')
import use_gin
print(use_gin.my_other_func())
```

use_gin.py

```
import gin
@gin.configurable
def my_other_func(a, b, c):
  return a, b, c
```